# requireJS and Google+ Javascript API

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have been trying this a while and I am totally stuck on this issue and hope someone can give me some ideas how I can solve this.
The problem is here.

I would like to use Google Javascript API for my site login.
My javascript is

```
define(function (require) {
    init = function(){
        require( ['https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton'], function(gapi){
            renderButton();
        });
    },
    renderButton = function(){
        console.log("renderbutton called");
        gapi.signin2.render('google-signin', {
            'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
            'width': 151,
            'height': 25,
            'longtitle': true,
            'theme': 'dark'
        });
    },
});
```

When I do this, it returns error message with "ReferenceError: gapi is not defined"

so I have tried as below but no luck.

```
define(function (require) {
    init = function(){
        require( ['https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton'], function(gapi){
            renderButton(gapi);
        });
    },
    renderButton = function(gapi){
        console.log("renderbutton called");
        gapi.signin2.render('google-signin', {
            'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
            'width': 151,
            'height': 25,
            'longtitle': true,
            'theme': 'dark'
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: Not totally sure, but I think you just need to pass gapi into renderButton.. I.E., renderButton(gapi);.  Require seems to load your gapi module into the current scope but it can't be accessed by another parallel function's scope without being passed as a parameter

Comment: Thanks Grumble Snatch. I have tried as above. I am not sure that's what you meant. I understood what you mean but that still complaints that gapi is not define.

Answer (score 2):

I set up a requirejs config like this:

```
window.require = {
    "shim": {
        "gapi": {
            "exports": "gapi"
        }
    },
    "paths": {
        "gapi": "https://apis.google.com/js/platform"
    }
}
```

Then I can do:

```
require(['gapi'], function (gapi) {
  gapi.load("", function () {
    // ..whatever..
  });
});
```

It's...a weird library though. I was trying to do the signing library and ended up needing to do this

```
gapi.load('auth2', function () {
  gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_CLIENT_ID
  });
  gapi.load('signin2', function () {
    gapi.signin2.render('g-signin', options);
  });
});
```

So you may want to set up a 'google-signin' loader. [requirejs loader plugins](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html). Basically it would look like this:

```
define('gapi', {
    load: function (name, req, onload, config) {
        //req has the same API as require().
        req(['gapi'], function (gapi) {
            gapi.load(name, function () {
              onload(gapi[name]);
           });
        });
    }
});
```

And then you can just:

```
require(['gapi!auth2', 'gapi!signin2'], function (auth2, signin2) {
  auth2.init({client_id: CLIENTID});
  signin2.render(...);
});
```

Comment: Apparently this does not seem to work properly (anymore) since `define('gapi')` overwrites the one from the `shim`. So you actually need to use a different name in `define()` to avoid this conflict. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

I know I asked the question but I was finally able to make it work.
I am not sure if I did correct way.
So please let me know if there is a better way to approach.

My javascript is

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";
    var $ = require('jquery'),
    ....
    ....
    .... includes other codes

    require( ['https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js'], function(){
        var renderButton;

        window.gapi.signin2.render('google-signin', {
            'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
            'width': 151,
            'height': 25,
            'longtitle': true,
            'theme': 'dark',
            'onsuccess': onSuccess,
            'onfailure': onFailure
        });
    });
}
```